# Работа с данными полученными из БД Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

подскажите, есть код, который открывает поток на чтение данных из БД оракл

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("тут селект", connection);
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
```

селект получает три столбца из таблицы, каждый столбец имеет порядка 50 тыс записей
вопрос: как используя этот самый поток создать массив объектов с тем кол-вом столбцов и записей сколько отдаст сам селект?

Comment: Вам чего то не хватает [в примере на офф доке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Answer (score 0):

> как используя этот самый поток создать массив объектов с тем кол-вом
>   столбцов

Воспользоваться свойством `FieldCount`

> записей сколько отдаст сам селект

Смысл `ExecuteReader` в том, что он начинает возвращать данные еще до полного получения данных => тебе никак не узнать фактическое кол-во записей пока ты полностью не прочитаешь все строчки.

Как следствие, для этой задачи проще всего воспользоваться динамическим списком `List<T>`.

А если вам все таки нужно в конечном итоге куда-то передать массив, то `List<T>` имеет метод `ToArray()`.

Comment: прочитать через while ?

Comment: Ну да. While reader.MoveNext(). Либо почитать, как пользоваться DataAdapter;ом- в него можно пулнуть ридер и на выходе получить DataTable. Минус в том, что это не всегда удобно, особенно когда запрос возвращает много данных и нужно ждать полного выполнения без возможности работы с промежуточными данными.

Comment: While(reader.Read()){}